# How to pattern match multiple values in Idris/Agda/Coq?

Tags: coq, agda, dependent-type, idris

I want to capture type validity in my `Expr` definition, and there is a problem when I'm defining `Add`, which is expected to be followed by `Decimal` or `Whole` arguments, but I don't know how to pattern match them both. following is my trials:

1st trial :

```
data DataType = Text | Decimal | Whole

data Expr : DataType -> Type where
    Add : (Expr Decimal) -> (Expr Decimal) -> Expr Decimal
    Add : (Expr Whole) -> (Expr Whole) -> Expr Whole
```

2nd trial:

```
data DataType = Text | Decimal | Whole

data Expr : DataType -> Type where
    Add : (Expr ty) -> (Expr ty) -> Expr ty
```

3rd trial:

```
data DataType = Text | Decimal | Whole

data Expr : DataType -> Type where
    Add : (Expr ty@(Decimal | Whole)) -> (Expr ty) -> Expr ty
```

In 1st trial, I'm told that I can't define `Add` twice.  And in 2nd trial, I don't know how to add the constriant that `ty` must be one of `Decimal` and `Whole`. And 3rd trial is using some imaginary syntax which is not supported yet..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to essentially put a constraint on `ty`. One general way to do this is

```
data Numeric : DataType -> Type where
  decimal-numeric : Numeric Decimal
  whole-numeric : Numeric Whole

data Expr : DataType -> Type where
  add : Numeric ty -> Expr ty -> Expr ty -> Expr ty
```

You could make this nicer to use by using an instance/default argument for the `Numeric ty` argument to `add`, depending on the language that you are using. What exactly the `Numeric` type is is up to you. Here I used a simple dependent type, but you could also consider a record of functions in the style of a Haskell type class instance.

An alternative is to have a hierarchy of types

```
data NumericType : Type where
  Whole, Decimal : NumericType

data DataType : Type where
  Numeric : NumericType -> DataType
  String : DataType

data Expr : DataType -> Type where
  Add : Expr (Numeric nty) -> Expr (Numeric nty) -> Expr (Numeric nty)
```

Comment: thx a lot, I think this is the correct solution, but the code you provided is not working in Idris.  maybe it is Agda code ?

Comment: @luochen1990 In Idris constructors should start with uppercase letter and can't contain `-`. So try to replace `decimal-numeric` with `DecimalNumeric`. Should work, this looks like valid Idris.

Answer (score 1):

[@Twan van Laarhoven 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056807/304284) in Coq syntax.

```
Inductive DataType : Type := Text | Decimal | Whole.

Inductive Numeric : DataType -> Type :=
  decimal_numeric : Numeric Decimal
| whole_numeric : Numeric Whole.

Inductive Expr : DataType -> Type :=
  add ty : Numeric ty -> Expr ty -> Expr ty -> Expr ty.
```